# working with LINQ to Entities against multiple sql server databases

Tags: linq, entity-framework, database-connection, entities

I'm building a project combined of number of sites with common subject.

The sites rely on one central database that holds the common info for all of them.

In addition, each site has another database that holds its unique info (I will refer to it as unique-db in the next lines so I won't be misunderstood).

For example, the `Languages` table sits in the central db. That said, I suddenly noticed that I need to use the `Languages` table in one of my unique-db in order for the table to act as a FK so I don't have to create the same table again in the unique-db.

Do I have to create the same table again this time in the unique-db? Or is there a  way to connect tables from separate databases?

In addition, we decided using linq2entity and soon we're gonna run some complex queries against the different databases. Will I have a problem with this matter? 
How should I go on with that? Was it wise to split the data into a few databases?

I really appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: How about some `enter`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that might make your life easier is to create views of the central tables in each unique db.  Linq to Entities will pick up views as if they were tables.